# Handlebarjs - Access parent index - Uncaught Error: Scoped data references are not supported: undefined

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Have looked at the documentation and it should be possible to access the parent index using the following...

```
{{#each columns}}
    {{#each rules}}
        {{@../index}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But I end up with this error message:

**Uncaught Error: Scoped data references are not supported: undefined**

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so not long posting this I found the solution, the version of handlebarsjs in use on my web page was version 1!

This feature was introduced in **v2.0.0-alpha.1 - February 10th, 2014**

Tested this by replacing my version with a more recent one from http://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js/ and it works perfectly